How to divide the numbers between two number and see how many numbers there modulus = 0
I have a task that forbids me from using an array or String or loops only if conditions or switch cases. The task is that I need to take three numbers from the user and see the how many numbers between the 1'st two numbers there modulus with the 3'rd number = 0 then write the amount of those numbers
For example: Input: 5 12 6. Answer would be 2. Explanation: a = 5 b = 12 x = 6. What I want is how many numbers there modulus with x = 0. The problem is I want the numbers between a and b inclusive, so for this example the numbers are 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12. The answer is 2 since only 6 and 12 modulus 6 = 0.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Finished {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = one.nextInt();
        int b = one.nextInt();
        int x = one.nextInt();

        int res1 = b / x;
        int res2 = b - a;
        int res3 = res2 % x;
        int finalresult = res1 + res3;

        System.out.println(finalresult);
    }
}


I'm not sure I understand your requirement. Can you clarify why the answer would be 2?

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the number of results for n % x == 0 where n >= a and n <= b, in which case the expected result of 2 comes from the results {6, 12}?

yes exactly jsheeran

This can be solved mathematically, without using loops.

basically 5 12 6
a = 5
b = 12
x = 6
what i want is how many numbers there modulus with x = 0, the prob is I want the numbers between a and b so for this example its 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 , the answer is 2 since only 6 and 12 modulus 6 = 0
k314159

how would u do it exactly?

Use the fact that the numbers with modulus 6 = 0 are actually spaced 6 apart. And since you know the size of the range of the numbers to check, you do the maths.

I thought of that but I couldn't implement it could u give me an example?

As @k314159 suggested:

Use the fact that the numbers with modulus 6 = 0 are actually spaced 6 apart. And since you know the size of the range of the numbers to check, you do the maths.

Let's start working on that. Here is what to do. We need to find the smallest number that is greater or equal to a that is divisible by x. Then we find the largest number that is smaller or equal to b that is divisible by x. Then we got a range. When you divide the size of this range with x and add 1 you got the count. Let's go through step by step.
First lets find the Smallest number greater than or equal to A divisible by X . Here is the java code for that:
// Find the first number in the range [a, b] that is divisible by x
int rem = (a + x) % x;
int firstDivisible = rem == 0 ? a : a + x - rem;

Second let's find the Largest number smaller than or equal to A divisible by X . Here is the java code for that:
// Find the last number in the range [a, b] that is divisible by x
int rem = b % x;
int lastDivisible = rem == 0 ? b : b - rem;

Now all that is left to do is the count part.
int count;
if (firstDivisible > lastDivisible) {
    count = 0; // No numbers divisible by x in the range
} else {
    count = (lastDivisible - firstDivisible) / x + 1;
}

Now let's join all these codes together and test it.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    int x = sc.nextInt();

    // Find the first number in the range [a, b] that is divisible by x
    int rem = (a + x) % x;
    int firstDivisible = rem == 0 ? a : a + x - rem;
    System.out.println("First divisible is " + firstDivisible);

    // Find the last number in the range [a, b] that is divisible by x
    rem = b % x;
    int lastDivisible = rem == 0 ? b : b - rem;
    System.out.println("Last divisible is " + lastDivisible);

    // Calculate the count
    int count;
    if (firstDivisible > lastDivisible) {
        count = 0; // No numbers divisible by x in the range
    } else {
        count = (lastDivisible - firstDivisible) / x + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("The count is: " + count);
}

When we test this code with the parameters 5, 12 and 6 the output will be:
First divisible is 6
Last divisible is 12
The count is: 2

Hope this helps.

Why is your first one rem = (a + x)%x that reduces to a%x

@matt yeah you're right. I don't know actually, I got the code from here.

As @Sither Tsering points out, this is a good case for using recursion:
public int recursiveMethod( int min, int max, int divider, int result ) {
   if( min % divider == 0 ) result ++;
   if( min >= max ) return result;
   return recursiveMethod(  ++min, max, divider, result );
}

recursiveMethod( 5, 12, 6, 0 );

As you can see, we invoke the method, passing it the necessary parameters to perform the calculation, and one more in which it will save the result of the calculation.
The first if of the method, evaluates whether the min is divisible by divisor, in which case, it increases by "1" to result.
The second if, evaluates that min is not greater than max, if it is it returns result.
The final line, returns the recursion call, increasing the value of min by "1".

It's a terrible case for using recursion. It takes O(N) steps and O(N) storage where N = b-a, and stands in contrast to the O(1) solutions already presented. In additions, it violates the spirit if not the letter of the restriction "no loops" mentioned in the question.

@PresidenteJamesK.Polk, You are right, it demands more steps (as a counterpart, the code is shorter, it depends on the need, whether it is applicable or not), but I don't think recursion can be considered as a loop, since as you yourself comment, it increases memory usage.

In the situation you mentioned, we need to think in terms of mathematical formulas.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = sc.nextInt(); //First number
    int b = sc.nextInt(); //Second number
    int c = sc.nextInt(); //The number to be taken as mode

    // Determination of the lower bound
    int lowerBound = (a % c == 0) ? a : (a + (c - (a % c)));

    // Determination of the upper bound
    int upperBound = (b % c == 0) ? b : (b - (b % c));

    // Counting process
    int count = (lowerBound <= upperBound) ? ((upperBound - lowerBound) / c + 1) : 0;

    // Print the result to the screen
    System.out.println("Result: " + count);
}

Explanation:

The variable lowerBound finds the smallest number that is greater than or equal to a and a multiple of c.
The variable upperBound finds the largest number that is less than or equal to b and a multiple of c.
count calculates the number of numbers between these two limits. If lowerBound is greater than the upper limit, that is, if there are no numbers in the range, count is 0.

This code correctly calculates the number of numbers between a and b that are divisible by c and prints it to the screen.
You can check out explanation and example of similar problem on this website PrepBytes
This is the first answer I shared, hope it was useful.
